# Focus event jquery combobox/autocomplete

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, combobox, jquery

Trying to bind on focus event of autocomplete jquery plugin some another action(showing tooltip on wrap element)
jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$( "#municipality_cb" ).combobox({
                focus: function(event, ui) {
    //tipTip(); - tooltip script* 
                $("#municipality_wrap").tipTip({maxWidth: "auto", edgeOffset: 10}); 
                }

                });
});
```

html:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
//-combobox wrapper div for tooltip
<div id="municipality_wrap" title="Chose municipality: Karposh" style="float: left;">
<select id="municipality_cb" tabindex="2" data-placeholder="Choose ..." title="test">

        <option value=""></option>
            other options....  

    </select></div></div>
```

Tooltip doesnt showing at all. What I do wrong? Help please :)

Jquery autocomplete plugin(look event tab)
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#municipality_cb" ).focus(function() {
 //tipTip(); - tooltip script* 
        $("#municipality_wrap").tipTip({maxWidth: "auto", edgeOffset: 10}); 
        });
       });
```

Comment: thanks, @bassem but I need to use autocomplete() function like a trigger- thats the point. I know that I have to call ready() function first, I just miss it in example, to simplify the example code

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem...

The trick here is that the combobox replaces your select with an input, so instead of tying the focus to the select, I got this to work by tying it to the wrap:

```
$("#municipality_wrap input").focus(function() { ... });
```